# SQL to compare date held in access to today's date not working

Tags: sql, excel, vba, date, ms-access

I'm trying to run a query, as part of VBA code, which looks at all the records containing today's date in a date field and writes them to a record set. The following SQL statement doesn't work however.
It doesn't return any records, even though the DateEntered field definetely has records with today's date.

```
dim cn as new adodb.connection
dim rs as new adodb.recordset
dim SQL as string
SQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl1LinkAuths WHERE DateEntered = #" & Date & "# "
Debug.Print SQL
cn.Open cnDB
rs.Open SQL, cn, , adLockPessimistic
```

I use this form of database connection all the time and it works for other queries in my code, it's just the date recognition that's at fault.

Comment: At least use `BuildCriteria` to form right format of date/time `SQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl1LinkAuths WHERE " & BuildCriteria("DateEntered",dbDate,Date)`

Comment: Dates can vary in format depending on the server they are stored on. Have you tried getting the top 10 records without the Date match and compare (via a MsgBox) the date displayed with the Date field entered in the VBA

Comment: Is DateEntered having time part?

Comment: Might be possible, your date have different times stored and the one you are trying to compare have no time at all, or vice versa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options:

```
SQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl1LinkAuths WHERE DateEntered = Date()"
```

or:

```
Dim DateToday As String
DateToDay = Format(Date, "yyyy\/mm\/dd")
SQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl1LinkAuths WHERE DateEntered = #" & DateToDay & "# "
```

Comment: SQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl1LinkAuths WHERE DateEntered = Date()" worked a treat.

Comment: Can't believe it was that simple. I've been trying all sorts of date conversion combinations. Thanks you so much.